# Looking for an existing facility that contains enclosed areas with extreme temperatures

Tags: environment, temperature, death

I would like to create a scenario where an unarmed individual leads its victims into a room that can be fully enclosed and then heated up to unsafe temperatures such that the victim would likely explode from the temperature increase.

One item I thought of are the painting facilities used in automotive factories, but I am unable to determine if the area where the car body is heated would get hot enough and be an area that can be isolated.

Comment: "Explode"? Do you really mean explode? Heat will burn people but it won't explode them.

Comment: Was inspired by this https://www.livescience.com/63807-vesuvius-victims-brains-boil.html regarding some victims of the Vesuvius explosion did in fact have their heads explode at least. "What's more, they added, star-shaped fractures on some of the skulls likely indicate that the vaporization of blood and brain matter caused the skulls to explode like unpierced baked potatoes in the microwave."

Comment: *"A room that can be fully enclosed and then heated up to unsafe temperatures"* is called an oven or a furnace. Large high-temperature ovens are used in many industries. Try to find out how they make cement or metallurgic coke or bricks or ceramics etc.

Comment: @VillageIdiot explosions during Vesuvius eruption are very speculative - we don't see any explosions when cooking food, regardless of method, except... **microwaving**.

Comment: @Alexander - have you heard of bangers, of banger and mash fame?  They came by their name honestly.

Comment: @Willk splitting open when cooking is not exactly the same as exploding.

Comment: @Alexander the difference is in how much force is the split done with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are plenty of industrial facilities with enclosed spaces that can be heated to unsurvivable temperatures.

Unfortunately, most of them remain hot most of the time, because if it's not hot, it's not making money for whomever owns it, and in more than a few cases, letting it cool can irreparably damage the facility. Things like glass furnaces are heated 24/7 from the moment they're first put into use until they're decommissioned, because letting the ceramic main vessel of that furnace cool too quickly (like in ambient air) will cause it to crack. Coke furnaces, which "bake" coal in a dearth of oxygen to vaporize volatile impurities, are fairly large spaces, but again rarely empty or even cool enough to pass for a man-accessible space. Modern brick kilns tend to be open-ended on both sides and packed with stacks of bricks being cured, and again they are commonly kept hot 24/7 as the design allows brick to be fed in constantly. In no case are any furnaces like these going to be anywhere you are likely to entice a bad guy into entering.

Most other heated vessels in commercial use are too small to consider, such as commercial kilns or autoclaves. These are often no larger than a residential refrigerator, and wouldn't be something you could crawl through in order to get someone else to crawl in.

I think, given the reality that spaces built to contain fire are typically hard to access by design, are commonly kept hot because that wastes less energy and time than heating a cold chamber over and over, and at least in modern litigious and unionized America the hazards would be well-stated for hundreds of yards around the device, you're going to have to earn your stripes as a writer, and hand-wave a setting which would call for a space that could be sealed and heated at a moment's notice. Perhaps a specimen containment area, with a segmented main hallway that provides emergency containment and "sterilization".

---

There are other equally horrifying ways to go, similar in concept to what you have in mind. For instance, one *Dirty Jobs* episode featured a locomotive factory, which had a cargo-container-sized enclosure for washing engine blocks that were being reconditioned and rebuilt. The wash liquid is a highly corrosive mix of strong hydroxide and organic bases, basically the only level of "detergent" that can break down the thick petroleum sludges that build in these blocks' crankcases in any efficient timeframe, and it is delivered at boiling temperatures.

They recounted a story of finding a glass bottle, the shell of a metal flashlight, a belt buckle, and some unrecognizable lumps of metal in the bottom of a hastily-started wash cycle, and reasoned that a drunk homeless man must have crawled in there when they weren't looking. They didn't see him around the block they were lowering into the wash chamber, and he was apparently too drunk to protest the noise (or too afraid of getting caught to speak up). If they were right, the man would have gotten his last rude awakening at the first splash of a boiling hot soup of strong chemical bases, strong enough to dissolve the man's skin, bone, clothing, even the man's teeth from around the fillings; the only thing the wash liquid won't react with are most metals and glass.

They look a little more closely at what's in the wash chamber now.

Comment: consider (hardwood)charcoal kilns and some heat treating furnaces for steel tools, both have to be sealed and heated then allowed to cool so they can be cleared. attempting to clear them while hot ruins to product so they can't stay hot. as a bonus many are owned by small enough organizations they don't have very robust safety measures outside someone needs to be watching them while running. some have been in use for so long they predate safety regulations.

Comment: @John This is true, and would probably be the easiest solution, however signage is probably the very easiest safety retrofit possible. Safety interlocks might take millions of dollars to put in place; a sign saying "this place gets really hot and if you're in there when it does you will die" costs about $10.